# Trouble getting local Git Changes to push to remote branch

Tags: git, azure

I have a local Git repo linked to Azure Repos.I have a Master, Development and several feature branches. I want to push all of my changes to the development branch and then merge that to Master.

The issue is my git status keeps changing from "...up to date..." to "Your branch is ahead...". If I use git pull/git push, my git status says everything is good, but if I wait a few minutes, git status says my branch is ahead again. I'm not sure what I broke.

```
$ git status

On branch development
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/development'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean


$ git status

On branch development
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/development' by 14 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean


$ git branch -avv

  KJG---Initialize-expComputer                921b26b [origin/KJG---Initialize-expComputer] Updated output object
  KJG--Write-expLog                           cb0db50 [origin/KJG--Write-expLog] added test-function
  KJG-Continue-expComputer                    07a6edd [origin/KJG-Continue-expComputer] save
  NewFeature--Get-expADSite                   4c6d991 [origin/NewFeature--Get-expADSite] platyps update
* development                                 c38a0c5 [origin/development: ahead 14] !Deploy 4.1.4
  master                                      2e01d04 [origin/master: ahead 7] Merge branch 'master' of https://<The Azure Repo Path>
  remotes/origin/ARBranch                     7b4f849 removed mandatory bluebeam parameter from init-expComp
  remotes/origin/Development                  6e7b779 !Deploy 4.1.2
  remotes/origin/KJG---Initialize-expComputer 921b26b Updated output object
  remotes/origin/KJG--Write-expLog            cb0db50 added test-function
  remotes/origin/KJG-Continue-expComputer     07a6edd save
  remotes/origin/Master                       c33f046 Merge branch 'development' into Master
  remotes/origin/NewFeature--Get-expADSite    4c6d991 platyps update
  remotes/origin/NewFeature-expPing           2751a6d updated help
```

Comment: Strange. Did you really run git status twice in a row and get different results without doing anything at all between them ?

Comment: Yes.  I waited a few minutes in-between running git status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something explicit like 
`git push origin development:development` to ensure your local `development` branch is pushed to `origin/development` ?

**EDIT** (04/02/2020) : See my comment below also about using `development` and `Development` as two of your branch names

Comment: I tried that on both the Mater and Development branch.  After a little while Git status shows that the branches are ahead.  
`
$ git push origin master:master
Everything up-to-date

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 7 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
`

Comment: Looking at your branches you don't appear to have an```remotes/origin/development```, only a ```remotes/origin/Development```. Git will see ```development``` and ```Development``` as different branches seeing as it is case sensitive. ```development``` only appears as a local branch. This would suggest you haven't done ```git push origin development:development```. At any rate having two branches named ```development``` and ```Development``` only complicates things.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I created two extra branches and now I have 2 Master branches and 2 Development branches.  In an effort to fix this I removed the extra branches, however, I was not sure which one was the originals.  At this point, is it possible to restore my entire repository to before I accidentally created those extra branches?

Comment: If you have pushed your deleted branches you can't get them back unfortunately. Can you please accept and verify my answer if you're happy to do so ? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to fix this or at least stabilize my repo.  I deleted the extra branches at remote and local and got everything up to sync.

I had to run: git push --set-upstream origin Development to re-link the local and remote branch.